# Resize Columns Width on button click trigger in XAML - without code-behind

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Im trying to resize Columns width in XAML using button click without code-behind,when the button is pressed new data is loaded but till now no automatic resizing (which im trying now) ive tried several ways but every time i face a different problem, the solution must be Code-behind free!

the latest solution was to make style-event for the button, but the problem was within the Event i can not reach the columns width value, using TargetName for example,  (GridViewColumn.width defined as dataGridView2) or even (GridView defined as dataGridView1), it would give an error.

i have tried to make a Style for the GridView or GridViewColumn but also it did not work too, i made a style-event for the ListView but the button events (IsPressed etc..) were not recognized inside it (when you tap TargetName and Property) and gave an error!

Thank you in advance for your answers!

XAML:Code

Comment: Rather than resizing the column, can you not set its `Width` to `"Auto"` and resize an element inside the column instead?

Comment: Width Auto will work in the first time (initialization), but when button is pressed again and again new data will be stored, which is bigger than the first data!

Answer (score 1):

Add it to code behind, that is the precise instance where you actually need code behind. Where you need code behind. i.e. when you deal with strictly controls it is acceptable and easy to have code behind handle things like sizing etc. Keep it simple.

Comment: -1 The question author was quite clear that he did not want to use code behind. Furthermore, you have not even offered a solution other than to tell them to do exactly what they did not want to do. This should have been a comment at best.

Comment: +1  The OP seems to be under the impression that code-behind is evil. It is not. Code-behind is the perfect place for View logic. Alternatively, you can even hide it away in a reusable [Attached Behavior](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28959/Introduction-to-Attached-Behaviors-in-WPF).

Comment: Code-behind is fine and ive already the code for it, but i need to do another XAML-code which is code-behind-free!